# 'The matter of fact is', - I came to believe this is grammatically accurate. Is it?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I suppose it's some kind of bastardisation of the phrase 'as a matter of fact', but with a grave undertone to it. Is it actually appropriate for use, especially in a formal email? Thanks.

Comment: It may be an error for "the material fact is", meaning the important, relevant fact is.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! @Peter

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a mistaken blend of "the fact is ..." and "as a matter of fact,...".
I've never heard it before.

I could imagine it in a conversation or an essay, where it referred to something that came before, for example,
A: "As a matter of fact, there are too many cars on the road."
B: "The 'matter of fact' is that we need more and better roads."

But that would be a rhetorical use, not an existing idiom.

Comment: Much appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use that phrase in a formal email. "Matter of fact" (along with "as a matter of fact") has become a set phrase to a certain extent, so it may sound unusual in different contexts.

You may have gotten "matter of fact" confused with "[the fact of the matter is . . .](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20fact%20of%20the%20matter%20is)". You can use the latter expression to emphasize that something is true.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I don't have enough 'reputation' points to upvote, but I appreciate this.